# Can AWS SSO generate a "friendly" issuer URL for SAML federation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, okta, aws-sso

I have SAML federation working between Okta and AWS SSO. Everything is fine, except that users performing IdP-initiated SSO see an "unfriendly" URL in their browser ("https://d-123456789a.awsapps.com/") once logged into AWS.

Is it possible to have a friendly name in the browser (aka, "https://friendly-name.awsapps.com/") after AWS login via IdP-initiated SSO, similar to when we're doing SP-initiated SSO? I believe this would require a different 'Issuer URL' from AWS SSO for the SAML connection, but I don't see any options for this in the AWS console.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey - If you haven't fixed this yet, here is the solution.
There is option in the AWS SSO console to change the SSO url while creating the SSO itself.
Go to Settings ->User portal
You will find the user portal URL and you change it to your convenience. One hiccup/point to be noted. You can just change the subdomain.
eg: https://friendlyurl.awsapps.com/start.